# matching the regex for year 2001 - 2100 in python

Tags: python, regex

```
r = re.compile('2100 | (20((0[1-9])|([1-9][0-9])))')
```

doesn't seem to work. but I think I did everything right to
match 2001 to 2100.. must be some misconception...
it doesn't even match 2100...

```
t = re.compile('\b(?:2100|(20((0[1-9])|([1-9][0-9]))))\b')
print (t.match('2000'))
print (t.match('2100'))
print (t.match('2020'))
print (t.match('1980'))
print (t.match('2050'))

None
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Why not simply check `2001 <= int(date) <= 2100`? As for your regex itself, the issue is most likely the spaces you've placed around the pipe `|` character, but without seeing your actual input, I can only guess.

Comment: @Vulcan: not if you are searching in a larger body of text.

Comment: `'|'.join(str(x) for x in range(2001, 2101))` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces, your regex works just fine otherwise:

```
r = re.compile('2100|(20((0[1-9])|([1-9][0-9])))')
```

You may also want to add negative look-arounds to ensure there are no more than 4 digits:

```
r = re.compile('(?<!\d)(?:2100|200[1-9]|20[1-9]\d)(?!\d)')
```

where I simplified the expression a little.

Comment: still not accepting valid years.. i must have missed something. but the solution by @JBernardo works although I haven't seen that construct before

Comment: @LeonardLie: what input are you using? Are there word characters before or after the digits?

Comment: Nevermind it's working now.. Thanks A LOT! worked without the anchors

Answer (score 2):

the regexp you need is `2100|200[1-9]|20[1-9][0-9]`

Comment: This regex accepts `2000`, which does not follow the contract.